# How can I write time's output to a file?

Tags: shell

I love to use "time" to tell me how long a script runs.
How ever, I don't know how to get the output "time" to a file.

```
time ls -l > outt
```

doesn't work, I only get the output of the "ls" in outt.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(time ls -l > outtLs) 2> outt
```

You can think as the time runs on a outer layer, and so we need a pair of brackets to contain it.
b.t.w 2> means stderr

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU version then use `-o` or `-a` options.

**GNU options:**

```
-o FILE, --output=FILE
Do not send the results to stderr, but overwrite the specified file.

-a, --append
(Used together with -o.) Do not overwrite but append.
```